# Use Canon MX510 as scanner

Tags: canon, scanner

I'm trying to scan from my Canon PIXMA MX515 via the network.

What I've tried so far:

- SimpleScan recognizes Scanner, but says it couldn't establish a connection.
- xsane tells me `Error while opening pixma:MX510_PixmaMX515.local:8612: Operation not supported`
- Added bjnp link to `/etc/sane.d/pixma.conf`, problem stays.
- VueScan works without problems, but I don't want to pay $40 just to be able to use my scanner.

NOTE: `man sane-pixma` says that MX510 series is included, but marked as experimental and may still need some work.

What can I do to get the scanner working? Printing (ipp) works without problems.

I'm using Raring x64

Comment: Are you now on 14.04 or are you still on 13.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your additional drivers tab in software & updates.

Or these sites can help:

http://support-hk.canon-asia.com/contents/HK/EN/0100412002.html

http://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/canon_mx510.html

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/canon-drivers-for-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/

http://www.driverlook.com/canon-pixma-mx512-all-in-one-printer-driver-linux-mac/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! Still neither xsane nor Skanlite can open the scanner (although they detect it now), but i can use Canon's SkanGear MP, which works pretty well.